# Spyder: How to edit a python script locally and execute it on a remote kernel?

Tags: python, ipython, remote-debugging, spyder

i am using Spyder 2.3.1 under Windows 7 and have a running iPython 2.3 Kernel on a Rasperry Pi RASPBIAN Linux OS.

I can connect to an external kernel, using a .json file and this tutorial:
[Remote ipython console](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/ipythonconsole.html)

But what now? If I "run" a script (F5), then the kernel tries to exectue the script like:

```
%run "C:\test.py"
```

ERROR: File `u'C:\\test.py'` not found.

This comes back with an error, ofc, because the script lays on my machine under c: and not on the remote machine/raspberry pi. How to I tell Spyder to somehow copy first the script to the remote machine and execute it there?

If I check the "this is a remote kernel" checkbox, I cannot connect to the existing kernel anymore. What does that box mean? Will it copy the script via SSH to the remote machine before execution?
If I enter the SSH login information, I get an "It seems the kernel died unexpectedly" error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial that you mention is a little bit our of date as Spyder now has the ability to connect to remote kernels. 
The "This is a remote kernel" checkbox, when checked, enables the portion of the dialog where you can enter your ssh connection credentials. 
(You should need this unless you have manually opened the required ssh tunnels to forward the process ports of your remote kernel... )

Besides, the ipython connection info (the json file) must correspond to the remote kernel, running on your raspberry pi.

Finally, there is no means at this time to copy the script lying on your local pc when you hit run. The preferred method would actually be the reverse: mount your raspberry pi's filesystem using a tool like sshfs and edit them in place. The plan is to implement an sftp client in Spyder so that it will not be required and you will be able to explore the remote filesystem from Spyder's file explorer.

To summarize:

1) assuming that you are logged in your raspberry pi, launch a local IPython kernel with 
    ipython kernel. It should give you the name of your json file to use, which you should copy to your local pc.

2) in spyder on your local pc, connect to a remote kernel with that json file and your ssh credentials

I know that it is cumbersome, but it is a first step..

Comment: So, lets say I connect through a already existent json file to the iPython kernel on the remote machine. That works already without the "This is a remote kernel" checkbox. **Why do I need to input any SSH credentials? Would Spider then login into my raspberry and start an ipython kernel there and fetch the json file for me?** I used samba to be able to load the script from the rasperry pi's home directory. Then connected to a kernel. So I can edit the file locally, then tab into the ipython console and manually "run xyz.py" (without F5). Well this should work. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using a password-less ssh connection, then you don't need to check the *This is a remote kernel* box. I presume that's your setup because otherwise I don't understand how you're connecting to your rasperry pi. In any case, the functionality is there to help users open ssh tunnels so that they can connect automatically to kernels in other machines. But if you don't need it, then you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

After a search in the `site-packages\spyderlib` directory for the keyword `%run`, I found the method(in `site-packages\spyderlib\plugins\ipythonconsole.py`) which constructs the `%run` command:

```
    def run_script_in_current_client(self, filename, wdir, args, debug):
    """Run script in current client, if any"""
    norm = lambda text: remove_backslashes(to_text_string(text))
    client = self.get_current_client()
    if client is not None:
        # Internal kernels, use runfile
        if client.kernel_widget_id is not None:
            line = "%s('%s'" % ('debugfile' if debug else 'runfile',
                                norm(filename))
            if args:
                line += ", args='%s'" % norm(args)
            if wdir:
                line += ", wdir='%s'" % norm(wdir)
            line += ")"
        else: # External kernels, use %run
            line = "%run "
            if debug:
                line += "-d "
            line += "\"%s\"" % to_text_string(filename)
            if args:
                line += " %s" % norm(args)
        self.execute_python_code(line)
        self.visibility_changed(True)
        self.raise_()
    else:
        #XXX: not sure it can really happen
        QMessageBox.warning(self, _('Warning'),
            _("No IPython console is currently available to run <b>%s</b>."
              "<br><br>Please open a new one and try again."
              ) % osp.basename(filename), QMessageBox.Ok)
```

I added the following code to convert paths after `else: # External kernels, use %run`

```
            # ----added to remap local dir to remote dir-------
            localpath = "Z:\wk"
            remotepath = "/mnt/sdb1/wk"
            if localpath in filename:
                # convert path to linux path
                filename = filename.replace(localpath, remotepath)
                filename = filename.replace("\\", "/")
            # ----- END mod
```

now it runs the file on the remote machine when I hit F5.
I am on `Spyder 2.3.9` with samba share mapped to z: drive.

Comment: Can you provide more details? When you hit F5, it seems like your Windows Spyder would try to copy the code from the remote machine and execute it on Windows? Don't you need to open an SSH connection to actually send the execution command over to the remote host?

Comment: I set up the spyder to connect to a remote ipython kernal using the json file as mentioned by op, when f5 is hit, spyder sends `%run filepath` to the ipython kernal, op has the error occurs because no the filepath does not exist on the remote machine, I mapped samba file share to z: drive so that the remote has

Comment: 2nd part (sorry, I accidentally hit submit) the remote machine has the same file (before the command is sent, spyder also save the file), the code in my answer translates the local filepath to remote filepath. As for the second question, I don't think ssh is necessary, however I do use the ssh option in spyder but I think it only does port forwarding (because I have firewall on the remote machine).

Comment: I see, thanks! I launched the kernel on my remote Ubuntu server, and I copied the corresponding json file over to my Windows machine. Then I entered the info in the "connect to existing kernel" dialog box, but when I click connect, it says "Can't open SSH tunnel, Paramiko not available". Any ideas on what to do next?

Comment: Just do `pip install Paramiko` on your local machine, depending on your python site-packages location, you might have to run cmd as Administrator to install.

Comment: I made an helper that does exaclty this, by redefening  `%run`, if anyone is interested. https://github.com/aulemahal/RunElsewhere

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use Spyder cells to send the whole contents of your file to the IPython console. I think this is easier than mounting your remote filesystem with Samba or sshfs (in case that's not possible or hard to do).

Cells are defined by adding lines of the form `# %%` to your file. For example, let's say your file is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def f(x):
    print(x + x)

f(5)
```

Then you can just add a cell at the bottom like this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def f(x):
    print(x + x)

f(5)

# %%
```

and by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> above the cell line, the full contents of your file will be sent to the console and evaluated at once.

Comment: Cool!, didn't know that. I works. Unfortunately I encountered, that you cannot STRG+C a remote kernel. In my application I am running a animation on some external LED stripe indefinitely. If you press STRG+C spyder tells you "---------------------------
IPython
---------------------------
Kernel process is either remote or unspecified. Cannot interrupt
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
" So I will change the program to an ending loop after writing some cycles with the Raspberry's PWM GPIO pin.

Comment: Yes, it's not possible to interrupt external kernels right now. See this [IPython issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1004) for some discussion about it.

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd make my first post to update Roy Cai's answer for Spyder 4 in case anyone is looking for this. Roy's answer worked flawlessly for me. Spyder 4 has moved the relevant code from where it was when he wrote the answer. The method is now in \Lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole and the python file is plugin.py.

Everything otherwise works the same as it used to - The place to insert the modified code is the same, and the same update fixes it.

(incidentally - yay for the ability to save login info for logging into remote kernels in Spyder 4!)