# Run Spyder's Python on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, spyder

I returns after all steps are noted above (Quant's "To summarize:" section) ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699356/spyder-how-to-edit-a-python-script-locally-and-execute-it-on-a-remote-kernel)) and still get "Unable to connect IPython kernel-2575.json" message .

I am using AWS ubuntu instance and the kernel-2575.json was downloaded from that instance (so it's local) after ipython kernel command . I am using .pem file provided by Amazon on Ssh key file. I am not sure it is right .

Any help what I miss ?