# Connect remote server to spyder for running Python Code

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, remote-server, spyder

Here is what I am trying to do. I have a Windows VM and another Linux VM which is used as server. I have Spyder installed on my Windows VM and would like to run my Python code in Spyder on remote Linux server.

I did try using option in Spyder called "Connect to remote kernel" but it did not work and I am getting error "Could not open ssh tunnel ; Paramiko not available". I was using username@servername:22 for making ssh connection. Needless to say, I am able to ssh the machine using putty but not using Spyder. Any ideas how should I fix this?

Comment: Did you try installing paramiko?

Comment: @user6586072 Hi, Im having the same problem. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: you may find this thread helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699356/spyder-how-to-edit-a-python-script-locally-and-execute-it-on-a-remote-kernel

Comment: Show your code. Are you including Paramiko?

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to make a connection to an external server, here is the [link](https://medium.com/@mazzine.r/how-to-connect-your-spyder-ide-to-an-external-ipython-kernel-with-ssh-putty-tunnel-e1c679e44154) explaining step by step.

Basically, you have to connect your client PC to the server through a PuTTY SSH tunnel, it will allow to redirect the client ports to the correct ipython kernel server ports.