# Spyder, Run script located on remote server

Tags: python, spyder

I am starting to use Spyder to edit code located on a remote server.
I managed to connect to the kernel of my remote server.
In order to be able to open and save (download, upload) the scripts, I installed Expandrive, that mapped the server as if it were an external hardrive on my machine. The server OS is Linux, my local one is Windows.

I thought that should work, but I am still receiving the error `file not found`.

[image]

Any idea why?

On that other post: [Spyder: How to edit a python script locally and execute it on a remote kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699356/spyder-how-to-edit-a-python-script-locally-and-execute-it-on-a-remote-kernel),  it is suggested (second answer) to add some specific code to the `%run` command file in order for the program to understand the dirpath syntax of linux.

```
    # ----added to remap local dir to remote dir-------
    localpath = "Z:\wk"
    remotepath = "/mnt/sdb1/wk"
    if localpath in filename:
        # convert path to linux path
        filename = filename.replace(localpath, remotepath)
        filename = filename.replace("\\", "/")
    # ----- END mod
```

Do you think that would adress my problem?

Comment: It might be a configuration problem in Spyder of your remote server connection. What I understand of the screenshot is that your remote server try to reach a path of "Z:\notebook....etc" which obviously it is your local path....so i would say it is a problem of connection config in Spyder

Comment: I would check out these two links: https://medium.com/@halmubarak/connecting-spyder-ide-to-a-remote-ipython-kernel-25a322f2b2be https://medium.com/@mazzine.r/how-to-connect-your-spyder-ide-to-an-external-ipython-kernel-with-ssh-putty-tunnel-e1c679e44154

Comment: A couple of suggestions to try (I do not use Spyder): (1) It *looks as though* the quotation marks are not needed.  Have you tried doing it as raw text? (2) I think Spyder wants the forward slash instead of the backslash for folder levels.

I doubt either helps, but they are easy to try.

Comment: I had tried setting this up 2 years ago but gave up due to similar errors.. Now I work with PyCharm Pro, it has all this functionality and more.. The pro version is free if you have are a student..

Comment: Yes or work on your local.. My conclusion :)

Comment: just use ftp to down- and upload your files...

Answer (score 1):

The path for the `%run` magic needs to be *the path that the **server** sees, not the client*.  You are passing the path from the *client's* perspective.

When you type `run Z:/blah/blah/blah.py`, your terminal *sends that path to the IPython server to execute*.  The server looks for the path `Z:/blah/blah/blah.py`, but since it doesn't exist *on the server*, the command fails with a file not found error.

The easiest solution is to just run the command with the path the server expects:

`%run /path/to/blah/on/server/blah.py`

---

Bottom line: remember that the *server* cannot access files that the *client* terminal is running on.